# how to write HashMap<String, IfcClass>() in php

Tags: java, php, hashmap

Can you please anyone tell me how to write the below java code in php.

```
 private HashMap<String, IfcClass> idCacheMap = null;
 HashMap<String, IfcClass>()
```

My basic concern is how to write Java HashMap in php and is there any alternative in php.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is usual `array('string' => Object)`. It works like HashMap.

Comment: But if you need concretely class HashMap you can create class, that implements Countable and ArrayAccess interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is doing the same job.